# Circular layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I need to develop an app to design a watch, as a beginner to android, i'm in need of two suggestion,

1) How to arrange the tick (for each hour in a watch) circularly?

2) Am i go with custom layout to arrange the ticks and labels? or use the same logic inside a method itself?

I hope the question is clear, Thanks in advance.

Joy Rex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading your question ther very first thing came in my mind is

[GaudgeView](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView)

You may need to customize it for second and minute hand. But you will have lot more clear idea with this widget to start with.

Its extends the View class and works on Canvas.
He has provided some customizations options too.

Comment: @Hardik_Trivedi Thanks for the suggestions, i will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
How to arrange the tick (for each hour in a watch) circularly?
```

I would recommend using an **image** for that because it would be easy and faster in `rendering` it on the canvas rather than drawing each tick on the canvas, you can create the image in `Photoshop` or your favorite editing tool.

```
Am i go with custom layout to arrange the ticks and labels? or use the same logic inside a method itself?
```

Yes you need custom layout, if you are planning to implement **animation** of the `big and small hand` of the clock you can can again create an image for small and big hand and draw it in canvas and for animating you can use the `matrix.postRotate` from the [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) class to rotate the arms of the clock each second,minute,hours.